# Animate a circle plus button to a pill shape on hover with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a circular button with a plus icon inside it. On hover, the circle animates to a pill shape.

I want to achieve two things:

1. Move the plus icon to the left on hover.
2. Text (like read more) fades in from the right and stops in the middle of the pill shape at the same time.

I was able to animate the circle to the pill shape smoothly but I can't control the plus icon (which moves to the middle of the pill shape instead of going to the left). I also couldn't figure it out how to add the text.

Thanks

```css
    .My-circle-Button { width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 25px; 
    background: none; transition: width .5s ease; color:#000; border: 4px solid 
    #000; }

    .My-circle-Button:after { content: "+"; font-size: 2.6em; line-height: 
    37px;}

    .My-circle-Button:hover { width: 240px;}
```

```html
<button class="My-circle-Button"></button>
```

```
<button class="My-circle-Button"></button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Kindly check out this snippet.

```css
.My-circle-Button { width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 25px; 
background: none; transition: width .5s ease; color:#000; border: 4px solid 
#000; position: relative; padding-left: 30px; color: #000; overflow: hidden; text-align: center;}
.My-circle-Button span { white-space: nowrap; transition: all ease .3s; opacity: 0; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; transition: all ease .3s;}
.My-circle-Button:after { content: "+";
    font-size: 2.6em;
  height: 50px;
    left: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0; }

.My-circle-Button:hover { width: 240px;}
.My-circle-Button:hover span{ opacity: 1; transition-delay:.3s;  transition: all ease .3s; }
```

```html
<button class="My-circle-Button"><span>Read More</span></button>
```

Comment: Hello Anmol,
Thank you very much for the answer, I think this is it! :)
Appreciate your help.

Comment: @AshSami it is great that it helped you. Please dont forget to mark my answer and vote it :-)

Comment: I don't know how (I'm new here) but I will find and do it Anmol :)

Comment: pretty much the same as what I've done https://jsfiddle.net/0a76bzfk/8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:after` and `:before` pseudo element and using `absolute` position to align the `+` symbol on left side. I have not done exactly what you want but this will give you the idea on how to go further. Look at the snippet.

```css
.My-circle-Button { width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 25px; 
background: none; transition: width .5s ease; color:#000; border: 4px solid 
#000;  position:relative; }

.My-circle-Button:before { content: "+"; font-size: 2.6em; line-height: 37px; position:absolute; top:3px; left:11px;}


.My-circle-Button:hover { width: 240px; position:relative; }
.My-circle-Button:hover:after { content: "read more"; font-size: 1.5em; line-height: 37px; position:absolute; right:60px; top:2px;}
```

```html
<button class="My-circle-Button"></button>
```

Comment: Hello Suresh,
Thank you very much for the answer :)
Appriciate your help